# SSIS Package Level deployment

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

In SSIS Package Level deployment  child package parallel execution is happening. In one execution point there is three execution record that also needs to execute parallel.   If I put debug point on 2nd  then it's working as expected otherwise it's always executing first. According to the picture of my child package if put debug point in B then only B is executing which is expected behaviour. But if I didn't put debug point then its always executing A.I am new in SSIS don't know much about terminology, please help.[image: SSISChildPackage]

Comment: Your question isn't fully clear and the picture too isn't helping as there are four squares with A,B,C listing in them. If I understand it right, there are three control flow tasks that you are trying to run in parallel but when you do execute only one i.e. 'A' starts running. On putting debugger, 'B' is getting executed but not 'A'.  Is that right?

Comment: A,B,C are in sequence container and 4 sequence container is there and they will execute parallel. so out of these now according to my input it will run only first A,B,C container. Condition wise it should run B  but if I didn't put debug point in B then it's running A only.

Comment: Well, that doesn't make sense. If A,B,C belonging to first block, are to be run in parallel that is, if these tasks are not connected in a workflow kind, then no matter what condition you keep any of the tasks can run and am not sure how you are restricting only B to run. Additionally are you saying that in current condition i.e. putting a debug point in B, A runs and C doesn't run?